# how to replace the test.css with test1.css by jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have css file reference like 
how could i replace the test.css with test1.css by jquery. help with code snippet.

thanks

Comment: this question could use a bit more detail

Comment: please include your code to show that you have put some effort into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replaceStyle(old, _new) {
    var ns = $('<style>', {
        href: _new,
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
    });

    $.each(document.styleSheets, function(i, style) {
        if( style.href && style.href.indexOf('all.css') > -1 ) {
            $(style.ownerNode).replaceWith(ns);
        }
    });    
}
```

This should do it. You could use that like:

```
replaceStyle('app.css', '/mypath/css/new.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
originalCss = $('link[href*="test.css"]').attr('href');
newCss = originalCss.replace('test.css', test1.css');

$('link[href*="test.css"]').attr('href', newCss);
```

edit (or in a function like this):

```
    function replaceCss(oldCss, newCss) {

    originalHref = $('link[href*=' + oldCss + ']').attr('href');
    newHref = originalHref.replace(oldCss, newCss)
    $('link[href*=' + oldCss + ']').attr('href', newHref);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's how you can conditionally include one stylesheet or another.

```
if (something_is_checked_here) {
  $("head").append('<link href="test1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
} else {
  $("head").append('<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
}
```

Comment: the original stylesheet is already included. he is asking about replacing the existing one.